# using linq query with stringBuilder

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I want to create dynamic where clause in a LINQ query. I have one stringbuilder `sb` having append  values `Country=null || City=null || State=null` and one datatable that has column named Name, Lastname, Country, City, State. I want to compare `sb` values with datatable columns and get null / empty rows.

So I want a LINQ query like this:

```
var query = from p in datatable.AsEnumerable()
            where sb.tostring() // ------------error
            select p
```

but it returns an error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can do it. What you want to do is "eval" the string. You can't do it easily in C# (and I'll note that you would get all the table on your computer and only then filter it, so if the table is big, you would "kill" the sql server :-) )

Comment: If you really really want to implement your "eval" function, this is probably a good start: http://www.ckode.dk/programming/eval-in-c-yes-its-possible/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

```
var query = datatable.Where("Country==null || City==null || State==null");
```

You'll need to download and include the C# file in the link and add:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in LINQ. Dynamic LINQ might help you, but that's probably no the best solution for you.

Why are you creating the query as a string? You can just build the query itself dynamically. Have a look at [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).